Python scripts stops unexpectedly
Python scripts stops unexpectedly without any error in the middle, following a span of recursion errors.
Hello, I am making a fun project consisting in converting a .mp4 video into a ASCII "video" with sound. It worked great, until I decided I wanted to bring color using colorama:
import cv2,os
from tqdm import tqdm
import store
import threading

global frames_interval

def extract_frames_with_progress(video_path, output_folder):
    # Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)
    
    # Open the video file
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    
    # Check if video opened successfully
    if not video_capture.isOpened():
        print("Error: Could not open video.")
        return
    
    # Get the total number of frames
    frame_count = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    fps = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    frame_interval = 1 / fps
    print(f"Frame rate: {fps} frames per second")
    print(f"Time interval between frames: {frame_interval} seconds")

    frame_number = 0
    
    with tqdm(total=frame_count, desc="Extracting frames") as pbar:
        while True:
            # Read the next frame
            success, frame = video_capture.read()
            
            # If the frame was not read successfully, break the loop
            if not success:
                break
            
            # Save the frame as an image file
            frame_filename = os.path.join(output_folder, f"frame_{frame_number:04d}.png")
            cv2.imwrite(frame_filename, frame)
            
            frame_number += 1
            pbar.update(1)
    
    # Release the video capture object
    video_capture.release()
    print("Done extracting frames.")
    return frame_interval,frame_count

def get_terminal_size():
    import shutil

    size = shutil.get_terminal_size((80, 20))  # Fallback size if unable to get terminal size
    return size.columns, size.lines

def image_to_ascii(image_path, dimension):
    from PIL import Image
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
    
    # Initialize colorama
    init(autoreset=True)

    # ASCII characters used to build the output text
    ASCII_CHARS = "@%#*+=-:. "

    # Open image
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    
    # Get terminal size
    term_width, term_height = dimension
    
    # Adjust the image size to fit the terminal
    aspect_ratio = image.width / image.height
    new_width = term_width
    new_height = int(term_width / aspect_ratio / 1.8)

    # If new height is greater than terminal height, adjust both width and height
    if new_height > term_height:
        new_height = term_height
        new_width = int(term_height * aspect_ratio * 1.8)

    image = image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    
    # Convert the image to RGB
    image = image.convert("RGB")
    
    # Convert image to grayscale for ASCII mapping
    grayscale_image = image.convert("L")
    
    # Get pixel data
    pixels = list(image.getdata())
    grayscale_pixels = grayscale_image.getdata()

    ascii_img = ""

    for i in range(len(grayscale_pixels)):
        grayscale_pixel = grayscale_pixels[i]
        r, g, b = pixels[i]
        
        ascii_char = ASCII_CHARS[min(len(ASCII_CHARS) - 1, grayscale_pixel // (256 // len(ASCII_CHARS)))]
        
        # Apply color using RGB values
        ascii_img += f"\033[38;2;{r};{g};{b}m{ascii_char}"
        
        # Add a new line at the end of each row
        if (i + 1) % new_width == 0:
            ascii_img += "\n"
    
    return ascii_img

def delete_all_files(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        print(f"The directory {directory} does not exist.")
        return

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        try:
            os.unlink(file_path)
            print(f"Deleted file: {file_path}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to delete {file_path}. Reason: {e}")

def check_if_already_extracted_footage():
    video_path = "Converter/video.mp4"
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    frame_count = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    for index,filename in enumerate(os.listdir("Converter/frames")):
        pass
    fps = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    frame_interval = 1 / fps
    if index+1 == frame_count:
        return (True,frame_interval,frame_count)
    else:
        print(frame_count,index)
        return (False,None,None)
    
def play(play_event:threading.Event):
        import time
        import pygame

        pygame.mixer.init()
        movie_player = pygame.mixer

        music_path = f"C:/Users/stard/OneDrive/Documents/code/Converter/music.mp3"
        if os.path.isfile(music_path):
            movie_player.music.load(music_path)
            while not play_event.is_set:
                pass
            movie_player.music.play()

def convert_mp4_to_mp3(input_file, output_file=None):
    from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
    import os

    if output_file is None:
        base, _ = os.path.splitext(input_file)
        output_file = base + '.mp3'

    video_clip = VideoFileClip(input_file)
    audio_clip = video_clip.audio

    audio_clip.write_audiofile(output_file)

    audio_clip.close()
    video_clip.close()

def convert():
    global frames_interval
    
    try:
        al_extracted,frames_interval,frame_count = check_if_already_extracted_footage()
        if al_extracted == True:
            print("Similar file already exctracted. Use?")
            choice = input("Y/N : ")
        dimension = get_terminal_size()
        if al_extracted == False or choice.upper() != "N":
            delete_all_files("Converter/frames")

            print("Starting...")
            frames_interval,frame_count = extract_frames_with_progress("Converter/video.mp4","Converter/frames")
        with tqdm(total=frame_count, desc="Converting frames") as pbar2:
            for filename in os.listdir("Converter/frames"):
                frame = image_to_ascii(f"Converter/frames/{filename}",dimension)
                store.frames_list.append(frame)
                pbar2.update(1)
        convert_mp4_to_mp3("Converter/video.mp4", "Converter/music.mp3")
        print("Done converting")
        choice = input("Save movie for later? : Y/N")
        if choice.upper() == "Y":
            store.save_movie(store.frames_list,frames_interval)
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"error : {error}")


def view(ASCII_movie,frames_interval):
    import threading
    from rich.console import Console
    term = Console()
    import time

    play_event = threading.Event()

    Music_thread = threading.Thread(target=play,arg=(play_event,))
    a = 0
    
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    Music_thread.start()
    play_event.set()
    for index, element in enumerate(ASCII_movie):
        # Calculate the expected time for the current frame
        expected_time = start_time + index * frames_interval
        
        # Clear the console and print the frame
        term.clear()
        print(element)

        # Calculate how much time to sleep
        current_time = time.perf_counter()
        time_to_sleep = expected_time - current_time

        # Only sleep if there is time left
        if time_to_sleep > 0:
            time.sleep(time_to_sleep)

    Music_thread.join()

def browse():
    import json

    lib = store.get_all()
    dict = {}
    for index,element in enumerate(lib):
        print(f"{index+1} : {element[1]}")
        dict[str(index+1)] = element
    ch = input("View (number) : ")
    try:
        dict[ch]
        with open(os.path.join("Madness","music.mp3"), 'wb') as file:
            file.write(dict[ch][4])
        data = json.loads(dict[ch][2])
        view(data,dict[ch][3])
    except:
        print("Invalid number")

inp = input("Browse / Convert : B/C : ").upper()

if inp == "ERASE":
    store.delete_all()
if inp == "CHANGE":
    lib = store.get_all()
    dict = {}
    for index,element in enumerate(lib):
        print(f"{index+1} : {element[1]}")
        dict[str(index+1)] = element
    inp2 = input("Change name of (number) :")
    try:
        dict[inp2]
        name = dict[inp2][1]
        new_name = input("New name : ")
        store.change_name(new_name,name)
    except:
        print("Invalid number")
elif inp == "C":
    convert()
    input("Start")
    view(store.frames_list,frames_interval)
else:
    browse()

Suddenly, the scripts stopped working in the middle because of RecursionError:
(Yes i'm Using tqdm)
Converting frames:  26%|██████████████████████████████▉                                                                                        | 989/3800 [00:40<01:54, 24.48it/s] object address  : 0000023600510DC0 object refcount : 2 object type     : 00007FFAB1D4A730 object type name: RecursionError object repr     : RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded') lost sys.stderr
So, without knowing what to do, I just increased the recursion limit.sys.setrecursionlimit(10**9)
And, it worked... until 40%, where the scripts just stopped, with no error. When I mean 'stops', I mean it goes back to the cmd command line. I checked, I had enough memory, and no real recursion inside my code. But I searched, and i saw that to increase the recusrion limit, you could put your code inside a thread. So I did. threading.stack_size(10**8)
Now it went to a 100%, but it stopped before the mp4 to mp3 conversion. Converting frames: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3800/3800 [02:31<00:00, 25.03it/s]
I don't know what to do at this point...
